# How to generate an openSSL key using a passphrase from the command line?

Tags: openssl

First -  what happens if I don't give a passphrase? Is some sort of pseudo random phrase used? I'm just looking for something "good enough" to keep casual hackers at bay.

Second - how do I generate a key pair from the command line, supplying the passphrase on the command line?

---

I finally got it working using these commands, using exec() which it is generally reckoned not safe to use, being better to give the PassPhrase in a file. I can accept this risk as I am sure that the PHP will only ever be executed on my PC (which runs windows & doesn't have a PS command).

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout pass:foobar -out privkey.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -passin pass:foobar -pubout -out privkey.pub
```

Many many thanks to @caf, without whom this would not have been possible.

Only one regret - that, no matter how much I Google, no one can seem to get `openssl_pkey_new()` working with Xampp on Windows (which is the **proper** way to generate a key pair)

Comment: why is `openssl_pkey_new()` ... the "proper" way to generate a key pair?

Comment: Windows doesn't (normally) have `ps` but since Vista it has `wmic process get commandline`

Comment: Ah, Vista. Also know as "the only way from here is up Windows" ;-)

Comment: And, since I am waxing nostalgic on Redmond products, a few decades (AKA the blink of an eye) ago, there were 3 Widows editions available : [CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded_Compact), [ME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Me) and [NT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT), thus offering us Widows CE ME NT.  Fun fact/pop quiz: : CE was actually "Embedded Compact", so why, oh why, did they not title it Windows EC?

Comment: Tracing the output at https://lapo.it/asn1js/ shows all key readable without password. Then what should the password have protected?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

If you don't use a passphrase, then the private key is not encrypted with any symmetric cipher - it is output completely unprotected.

You can generate a keypair, supplying the password on the command-line using an invocation like (in this case, the password is `foobar`):

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout pass:foobar 3072
```

However, note that this passphrase could be grabbed by any other process running on the machine at the time, since command-line arguments are generally visible to all processes.

A better alternative is to write the passphrase into a temporary file that is protected with file permissions, and specify that:

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout file:passphrase.txt 3072
```

Or supply the passphrase on standard input:

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout stdin 3072
```

You can also used a named pipe with the `file:` option, or a file descriptor.

---

To then obtain the matching public key, you need to use `openssl rsa`, supplying the same passphrase with the `-passin` parameter as was used to encrypt the private key:

```
openssl rsa -passin file:passphrase.txt -pubout
```

(This expects the encrypted private key on standard input - you can instead read it from a file using `-in <file>`).

---

Example of creating a 3072-bit private and public key pair in files, with the private key pair encrypted with password `foobar`:

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout pass:foobar -out privkey.pem 3072
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -passin pass:foobar -pubout -out privkey.pub
```

Comment: +1 Great, that works! Thanks, if you can just help a teensy bit more then you get awarded the answer  ...   why won't this work?   openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -pubout -passout pass:foobar -out pubkey.pem

Comment: or, to put it another way - how to the public key from your command (which differed slightly from mine). I just need a matched pair. This is only "just good enough" security.

Comment: @Mawg: Your `openssl` command is outputting the public key corresponding to the supplied private key - public keys aren't encrypted (they're not secret), so using `-passout` makes no sense.  You probably want to use `-passin` there, to supply the passphrase that was used to encrypt the private key in the first step.  I've also added something to the answer.

Comment: @caf, thanks for the great feedback (+1 again). However, I am apparently too dumb to be allowed to use OpenSSL. I want the key in a file and, for some reason, `openssl genrsa 2048 -aes128 -passout pass:foobar -out privkey.pem` doesn't do that.  Can you please give me two commands - one to generate the private key into a file an a second to generate the public key (also in a file)? Sorry to be such a nuisance, but I have been playing around with it & just can't make it work :-(

Comment: and why -aes128? THe examples at http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#key-rsa use -aes256 (no that I understand it ;-)

Comment: @Mawg: OpenSSL doesn't like it if the `-out` param comes after the `2048` - really, that's supposed to be the last thing on the command line (I've updated my answer as such).  See the last example, I think that's what you want.  As for AES-128, [someone I trust in these matters](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html) recommends it over AES-256.

Comment: Thanks, I cobbled something together, see updated question for the answer

Comment: Note, on Windows, gnuwin32's openssl.exe generates a corrupt key when using `-passout stdin`. It will fail to decrypt with the same passphrase. If you're hitting this, try a linux/osx machine for the 'genrsa' step and it should decrypt in all other environments.

Answer (score 25):

`genrsa` has been [replaced by `genpkey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-genpkey.html)

> The use of the `genpkey` program is encouraged over the algorithm
> specific utilities because additional algorithm options and ENGINE
> provided algorithms can be used.

`genpkey` allows you to generate the following key types:

- `RSA` `RSA-PSS` `EC` `X25519` `X448` `ED25519` `ED448`

When run manually in a terminal it will prompt for a password:

```
openssl genpkey -aes-256-cbc -algorithm RSA -out /etc/ssl/private/key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
```

However when run from a script the command will not ask for a password so to avoid the password being viewable as a process use a function in a `shell` script:

```
get_passwd() {
    local passwd=
    echo -ne "Enter passwd for private key: ? "; read -s passwd
    openssl genpkey -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:$passwd -algorithm RSA -out $PRIV_KEY -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:$PRIV_KEYSIZE
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find a statement that `genrsa` replaced by `genpkey` in provided link or any man pages of both sub-commands. Instead I understand that `genpkey` is a general form of generating keys whereas `genrsa` is responsible for `RSA` algorithm.

Comment: @FredrickGauss, indeed, it literally states: "...encouraged over the algorithm specific utilities because additional algorithm options and... algorithms can be used...", and that highlights the reason.

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean "recommended".