# Scripting openssl to generate many certificates without manually entering password?

Tags: ruby, command-line, input, openssl, popen3

I have created a certificate authority and need to generate and sign 50+ certificates. I wanted to script this process. I don't want to have to manually enter a password 100+ times!

Here is the command I was getting hung up on:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout ~/myCA/tempkey.pem -keyform PEM -out ~/myCA/tempreq.pem -outform PEM
```

The problem is, it wants me to create a password with these prompts:

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

When I am just being asked for a password to input I can use the `-passin pass:mypass` command line option for `openssl`. But this does not seem to work for creating a password.

Also, it seems strange that a password is required when later I just end up removing it with:

```
openssl rsa < tempkey.pem > server_key.pem
```

I tried creating a simple Ruby script:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen2("openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout ~/myCA/tempkey.pem -keyform PEM -out ~/myCA/tempreq.pem -outform PEM") {|i,o,t|
    i.puts "mySecretPassword"
    i.puts "mySecretPassword"
}
```

But this does not seem to work either. I still end up with a manual prompt asking me to create a password.

Comment: There's an OpenSSL class in ruby's standard library. Try using that: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html I can't write a full example right now, but I'll try to do so later if I find time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is most of utilities that expects a password do require interactive terminal. So if you try to fake it (like you did with a Ruby script) it will not work. You could also try:

```
echo -n "pass\npass\n" | openssl req ....
```

While this will work with some programs, those what require interative shell will not work.

You are searching for the tool called expect. Install it on your UNIX/Linux/MacOS and see the man page:

```
man expect
...
Expect is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script.  Following the script, Expect
knows what can be expected from a program and what the correct response should be.  An  interpreted  language  pro‐
vides  branching  and high-level control structures to direct the dialogue.  In addition, the user can take control
and interact directly when desired, afterward returning control to the script.
...
```

You need to create "expect script", it really depends on your environment - what the application is asking for. If it is only a passwords, it should be simple. Here is more complex example: http://fixunix.com/openssl/159046-expect-script-doesnt-create-newreq-pem.html

I think this should work (you will maybe need to change it a bit):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn -console openssl req blah blah blah blah
expect "Enter PEM pass phrase:*" {send "password\r"}
expect "Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:*" {send "password\r"}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4300425/376366) you can use the `-passout pass:foobar` option to set a password via command line. For example:

```
openssl req \
  -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout ~/myCA/tempkey.pem -keyform PEM \
  -out ~/myCA/tempreq.pem -outform PEM \
  -passout pass:foobar \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=Test/L=Test/O=Test/CN=localhost"
```