# How do you convert an unencrypted PEM file to an encrypted format

Tags: encryption, ssh, terminal

I have an unencrypted PEM file I want to secure by requiring a passphrase to unlock (to prevent issues in the case where it is possibly stolen).

How would one go about converting it using a terminal command?

Comment: I thought the key could be passphrase protected not the pem itself.  Would this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294689/how-to-generate-a-key-with-passphrase-from-the-command-line do what you want or did I misunderstood the question ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this tutorial](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2013/05/24/improving-security-of-ssh-private-keys.html) contains the information you are looking for, more or less, I believe you just need to remove the -passing part:

```
$ mv test_rsa_key test_rsa_key.old
$ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 des3 \
    -in test_rsa_key.old \
    -out test_rsa_key -passout 'pass:super secret passphrase'
```

In any case, openssl is the tool you want to use.