# Openssl optionalCompanyName (optional Company Name) in command

Tags: openssl, attributes, command

I made one openssl command so I can automate it using scripting.  I find all the options by visiting different questions and sites but could not find option for "An optional company name", I tried "optionalCompanyName" but it did not worked.

```
(/C) Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:GB
(/ST) State or Province Name (full name) []:London
(/L) Locality Name (eg, city) [Default City]:London
(/O) Organization Name (eg, company) [Default Company Ltd]:XYZ
(/U) Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:XYZ
(/CN) Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:- $DOMAIN
(/emailAddress) Email Address [] :- some@some.com
(/challengePassword) A challenge password :- strongpass
(/?) An optional company name []:PROBLEM
```

Please help.

```
export domain=SOMEDOMAINNAME
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout $domain.key -out $domain.csr -subj "/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=XYZ/OU=XYZ UK/CN=$domain/emailAddress=some@some.com/challengePassword=strongpass/optionalCompanyName=PROBLEM"
```

Same command in multi line, so it is easy to read

```
export domain=SOMEDOMAINNAME
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout $domain.key -out $domain.csr -subj  
"/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=XYZ/OU=XYZ UK/CN=$domain/emailAddress=some@some.com 
/challengePassword=strongpass/optionalCompanyName=PROBLEM"
```

Visited links

- https://www.shellhacks.com/create-csr-openssl-without-prompt-non-interactive/
- https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/openssl-quick-reference-guide.htm
- https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/req.html#CONFIGURATION_FILE_FORMAT
  and few Stackoverflow questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defined attributes for the [subject and issuer fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.4) in a certificate are defined by [ITU X.520](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.520).

There is no "optional company name" item defined.

I think what you are referring to is the "Organization Name" attribute type.  This is defined with the LDAP-NAME of "O".

In you example:

> "/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=XYZ/OU=XYZ
> UK/CN=$domain/emailAddress=some@some.com
> /challengePassword=strongpass/optionalCompanyName=PROBLEM"

It's the "/O=XYZ" so the "Organization" (or company name) is "XYZ".

**Update:**

After some reading I see where you are coming from as I never some across this before:

"An optional company name:" is "[unstructuredName](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2985.txt)".

"unstructuredName" and "challengePassword" is part of a certificate request only. So it's NOT part of the subject.  So you shouldn't use "/challengePassword=strongpass" in your subject line.

You can see this in a default openssl.conf file:

```
[ req ]
attributes      = req_attributes

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20
unstructuredName        = An optional company name
```

Req attributes look to be ignored by most CA's.  See note in OpenSSL [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/openssl-req.html):

> **attributes**
>
> this specifies the section containing any request
> attributes: its format is the same as distinguished_name. Typically
> these may contain the challengePassword or unstructuredName types.
> They are currently ignored by OpenSSL's request signing utilities but
> some CAs might want them.

Currently openssl does not provide any way to set req attrbutes from the command line. So the only way to do this is with a custom conf file with those attributes set.

If you need to do this, I would create a conf file with the prompt set to "no" and use the -conf openssl paramater. Please note that the [format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081815/23235) changes a little when you set prompt to "no".

Since req atrributes are most likely ignored anyway, I would not bother setting them.