# Generation of private key using des3 gets stuck

Tags: ssl, heroku, openssl

I'm following [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#acquire-ssl-certificate) to generate a private key for an SSL certificate.

When I execute the command `openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048`, I get the following result:

```
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
..........................+++
..................................................+++
```

I can't get to the prompt where I'm supposed to enter the passphrase for the keys.

I don't understand why OpenSSL fails to complete. I've generated keys without triple DES, so I guess the error is in the encryption. How can I get this solved?

Comment: You also seem to be missing the `e is 65537 (0x10001)` output. You should probably ask on a site more appropriate to running commands, like [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow's niche is programming and development questions, and questions would ask about API calls like `RSA_generate_key_ex`.

Comment: That documentation looks a bit odd — it has you generate an encrypted private key, only to have you strip the encryption in the very next step and never use the encrypted version again. As a work around I guess you could just create an unencrypted key directly and use that.

Answer (score 19):

I saw this exact symptom in a Git for Windows shell.
It might be that it [gets stuck trying to ask for a password but can't.](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/836)
So as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4300425/268066) I added `-passout pass:MyPassword` and it worked.

Comment: Can you show the full command? I tried adding it at the end but then I get "Unable to load private key".

`openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048 -passout pass:MyPassword
`openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
`openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
`cp server.key server.key.copy
`openssl rsa -in server.key.copy -out server.key
`rm server.key.copy

Comment: Worked for me! Hint: The passout attribute is not allowed to be appended at the end of the string, but has to be in front of the number at the end of the string:

`openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout file:passphrase.txt 3072` Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4300425/268066

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to run `openssl` behind `winpty` (assuming you're within the MINGW64's `mintty` window), like so:

```bash
$ winpty openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048
Generating a RSA private key
....++++
....++++
writing new private key to 'key.pem'
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
(etc)
```

Whereas without `winpty` it gets stuck:

[image]

Comment: You deserve a few hundred points for this. May someone buy you lunch today!!