# openssl certificate request with pass phrase argument using api

Tags: openssl, arguments, certificate

when creating a openssl certificate request using the library api, which is the function used to have the request with a pass phrase argument and how is the pass phrase generated (by openssl or provided).

Comment: It may be a good idea to add more details to your question like the platform you are using, the name and version of the library you are using. The name of the API function that has caused you a problem. And maybe some code pieces.

Comment: using OpenSSL 1.0.2p-fips need to know the api providing this functionality

Comment: the openssl command equalent will be   openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:password  -out privkey.pem 2048.   The pass phrase here is 'password'.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294689/how-to-generate-an-openssl-key-using-a-passphrase-from-the-command-line

Comment: this uses the exec() i need the API provided by the openssl because i need to investigate how are generating the passphrase and retrieving when opening the certificate again  Thank you for all the response Hamed