# openssl add password to keys with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl

on cli if you type this

```
openssl rsa -in cert_export_client.key -out cert_export_client.key
```

it will prompt to enter your passphrase. Is is possible to automate with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the the `os` module:

```
from os import system
system("openssl rsa -in cert_export_client.key -out cert_export_client.key")
```

The system function executes the given command in a subshell.

Comment: but then is prompt the to Enter pass phrase. How i can define the password as variable and automate together?

the output is : 

```
"Enter pass phrase for cert_export_client.key:"
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with openssl, but I can [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294689/how-to-generate-an-openssl-key-using-a-passphrase-from-the-command-line) a similar question that has been answered.